# What are some Security holes a website is exposed through document upload?

Tags: php, storage

I am new to the document storage space.  I am not sure what i am doing yet, but before i begin i wanted to know about the possible security threats one has when one allows document uploads and what is the best way to sanitize the data? I am using PHP and will allow images, word docs, pdfs, excel docs, etc.

And is this a good solution:

http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2009/01/secure-file-upload-in-php-web-applications/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two really obvious ones:

- If improperly done, a file uploader could allow the user to overwrite other people's files -- *including the PHP that runs the site*.  Make sure permissions are set so that the web server's account has read-only access to any directory but where stuff should be written, and that nothing in that directory can be executed.
- Users can upload (big) enough files to fill the site's disk quota.  Even if they can't, they can try -- and the server might not refuse the upload til after the whole file's been sent anyway, chewing up precious resources and possibly still filling the drive (if only for the time it takes to refuse the request and delete the temp file).

And that's just the risks to the server.  Files can contain malware that can affect other users.  You'll probably want to find a scanner for that stuff.

I'll suggest that if you want to let people upload files, you find a pre-written script that a lot of other people use and recommend.  Rolling your own is bound to cause you problems when someone does something that you never considered.

Comment: Is it also advisable to host these files away from our existing envrionment to something like Amazon storage or rackspace cloud storage?

Comment: If you have it already, it might be something to consider.  But the important part is that the server should never be allowed to write executables or execute uploads.  Ideally the application shouldn't even be able to *read* executables, lest they spill all their secrets about how stuff's done (and potentially what passwords to use!), so a separate account isn't too bad an idea if you don't know PHP.  But a decent uploader will minimize a lot of these issues without you having to pay another bill.

Comment: So i am just going to make sure the files are uploadable but not executable and downloadable.... how do i set permissions?

Comment: Have a tmp upload directory - get server to process and check accordingly, then move to appropriate folders. Assign an 777 permission to the uploaded data folder. Nice little link: http://goo.gl/eodHT Connect to the server via FTP, right click folder and set permissions. Depends on your FTP Client...

Comment: On a *nix host, 644 for files, 755 for directories is generally safe...but it depends on the config -- particularly what user the web server runs your PHP as, and who's listed as the "owner" when you list the files.  Ideally, those two should not match!  No directory except the upload dir (wherever the files end up going) should have write permissions.

Answer (score 2):

There are a vast amount vulnerabilities, when allowing a user to upload files. Potential, blocking unwanted file formats, can help limit the possibilities of someone being able to upload a shell, and root your server. **Affecting the integrity, confidentiality and availability of information on your servers.**

There also vulns within you forms control as well such as **XSS** (cross-site scripting) exploits...allowing a user to run malicious code. This could lead to malicious code being executed in users environments.

There also the possibilities, for vulnerabilities within your actual database as well i.e. **SQL** injections.

***Just don't let the server execute executable files...***

Risk from users uploading large files, utilising vital disk space and bandwidth.

Useful link for securing PHP upload scripts: **http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/file_upload.php**

Comment: Is it also advisable to host these files away from our existing envrionment to something like Amazon storage or rackspace cloud storage?

Comment: Good Point: Yes, cloud storage would be extremely useful, but then theirs controversial issues. Who owns the data in the cloud? you or amazon etc... Depends on the confidentiality of the information really, and potential Data Protection Act etc. For more info, have a read of the CIA Triad Model. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_security

Comment: I hadn't heard of any controversy over who owns the files.  Whoever's paying for the account does.  If the host has any ownership stake in the files, they probably don't qualify for any "safe harbor" exceptions -- so most hosts won't even think of trying to claim ownership.  The hosting agreements might grant the host a license to copy and distribute, though, so that they can store and send the files without some jackass suing them for doing their job.

Comment: Screw w3schools.  They don't have a clue when it comes to PHP.  And people need to stop linking to them like some sort of resource.

Answer (score 1):

There are several threats you should be aware of:

- Malware like virus, worms, trojan horses and so on, especially if the uploaded files are accessible by other users.
- Files that can be executed on your system like php-files. If a user can upload a php-file to your webroot, he can execute arbitrary commands using something like passthru(cmd) or system(cmd).
- Illegal content. You don't want anything illegal on your server that could get you into trouble.
- Someone could upload HTML-files with javascript, using them for XSS attacks
- ...

Just to name some of them. You should take a look at the [OWASP Website](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload) concerning Unrestricted File Upload. You should find anything you need there.